# Meteor & Twitter-Bootstrap: Cannot change navbar-top menu names

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, navbar

I am using Meteor and Twitter Bootstrap.
The code below uses the Bootstrap navbar, and without Meteor I can modify "About", "Services", and "Contacts", and then the new names show up in the navbar-fixed-top.

**However, if I modify the menu names when using Meteor, the menu names only change in the toggled menu bar and not in the navbar-fixed-top.** How may I change the menu names in the navbar-fixed-top as well?

```
<head>
  <title>App name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title name</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li>
                      <a href="pimp.html">New name</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for the navbar of one of my Meteor apps:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

          <div class="container-fluid navbar-inner">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Something</a>
               </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->


          </div><!-- / container-fluid -->

    </nav>
    <!-- / navbar -->
```

Just write whatever you want instead of

> something

And it should work.